# Get a default value instead of `undefined` for non-existing array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the value `"0"` back when there's nothing written in the spreadsheet cell whose data I get returned as JSON in an API call. But the output is always `undefined`. I tried using `if else`, but it didn't work.

[image: IMG SHEET]

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/10Ct44JBW-CyoApJXIV87jeVU3Rr-fiLTdoTIJdbSwG8/values/page!A1:C3?key=AIzaSyArRlzwEZHF50y3SV-MO_vU_1KrOIfnMeI", function(result) {
    $.each(result.values, function(i, field) {
      $(".guide").append('<span class="field1">' + field[0] + '</span><br><span class="field2">' + field[1] + '</span><br><span class="field3">' + field[2] + '</span><br>');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.field1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color:green;
}
.field2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color:blue;
}
.field3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="guide"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `??` operator ([Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)) to replace `null` and `undefined` with something else, in this case, `0`.

For example: `(field[1] ?? 0)`

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/10Ct44JBW-CyoApJXIV87jeVU3Rr-fiLTdoTIJdbSwG8/values/page!A1:C3?key=AIzaSyArRlzwEZHF50y3SV-MO_vU_1KrOIfnMeI", function(result) {
    $.each(result.values, function(i, field) {
      $(".guide").append('<span class="field1">' + (field[0] ?? 0) + '</span><br><span class="field2">' + (field[1] ?? 0) + '</span><br><span class="field3">' + (field[2] ?? 0) + '</span><br>');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.field1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
}

.field2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: blue;
}

.field3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="guide"></div>
```

Comment: Ohh it worked perfectly. And in place of "0" would it be possible to return a " - " or " " too? Does it follow the same logic?

Comment: I linked the documentation, but yes. If on the left side of  `??` you have `null` or `undefined`, it will be replaced with the right side. You can put whatever you want to :)

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for the teachings. :DD